# For loop disaster, iterates more than it should

Tags: c++

Can someone help me find out what this would iterate 3 times when i tell it to only do one time int the forloop? I choose my mtype 1 and when i go to display that information(which this function is designed to do) it loops the 3 times instead of one.

EDIT: the reason i know its iterating more than it should is because the cout statement at the bottom of each if statement doesnt actually go there, im just using it to find where the problem is.

```
for (int itemno = 0; itemno < numItems; itemno++)
{

    if (mtype == *(type + itemno) || mtype == -1)
    {
        if (mtype == 2)
        {

            *(price + itemno) = calculatePrice(*(cost + itemno), *(hours + itemno));

            totalCost = totalCost + *(cost + itemno);
            totalHour = totalHour + *(hours + itemno);
            totalPrice = totalPrice + *(price + itemno);
            cout << setw(13) << left << canType << setw(13) << right << *(cost + itemno) << setw(16) << setprecision(2) << fixed << hours[itemno] << setw(16) << price[itemno] << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (mtype == *(type + itemno) || mtype == -1)
    {
        if (mtype == 3)
        {

            *(price + itemno) = calculatePrice(*(cost + itemno), *(hours + itemno));

            totalCost = totalCost + *(cost + itemno);
            totalHour = totalHour + *(hours + itemno);
            totalPrice = totalPrice + *(price + itemno);
            cout << setw(13) << right << *(cost + itemno) << setw(16) << setprecision(2) << fixed << hours[itemno] << setw(16) << price[itemno] << endl << endl;

        }
    }
    else if (mtype == *(type + itemno) || mtype == -1)
    {
        if (mtype == 4)
        {

            *(price + itemno) = calculatePrice(*(cost + itemno), *(hours + itemno));

            totalCost = totalCost + *(cost + itemno);
            totalHour = totalHour + *(hours + itemno);
            totalPrice = totalPrice + *(price + itemno);
            cout << setw(13) << right << *(cost + itemno) << setw(16) << setprecision(2) << fixed << hours[itemno] << setw(16) << price[itemno] << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (mtype == *(type + itemno) || mtype == -1)
    {
        if (mtype == 5)
        {
            *(price + itemno) = calculatePrice(*(cost + itemno), *(hours + itemno));

            totalCost = totalCost + *(cost + itemno);
            totalHour = totalHour + *(hours + itemno);
            totalPrice = totalPrice + *(price + itemno);
            cout << setw(13) << right << *(cost + itemno) << setw(16) << setprecision(2) << fixed << hours[itemno] << setw(16) << price[itemno] << endl << endl;
        }
    }   
    cout << setw(13) << right << *(cost + itemno) << setw(16) << setprecision(2) << fixed << hours[itemno] << setw(16) << price[itemno] << endl << endl;
}


cout << endl << setw(9) << left << "TOTALS: " << setw(5) << right << "$" << setw(12) << totalCost<< setw(17) << totalHour << setw(17) << "$" << setw(5) << totalPrice << endl;
cout << endl << horizontalLine << endl << endl;
```

}

Comment: what is the value of numItems?

Comment: To debug this, I'd suggest you print out (or view in debugger) the values of the loop control variables itemno and numItems inside the for loop, at the start and end.

Comment: numItems is a inventory  that is updated as the user adds individual pieces of candy to it. so if you go through the program and add 3 pieces numItems would be 3 the type of candy is stored in mtype and updated when numitems is.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @sj0h i dont know how to do that, im new to the whole c++ thing.

Comment: cout << "Debug: item " << itemno << " out of " << numItems << endl;

Comment: Are you new to programming? There are some general, language-independent techniques that are very useful in cases like this.

Comment: Save yourself some mess by writing `*(type + itemno)` as `type[itemno]`

Comment: Also, all those `|| mtype == -1` clauses are useless, since that and the inside condition can never both match.

Comment: In your test, you expect the `for` loop to iterate only once. Is that because `numItems` is 1?

Comment: Yes, at least numitems should be 1 since im only adding 1 hardy candy item for this test.

Comment: I went a replaced numItem with just one and it stopped the repetitions  but now it opens up the problem of why is numItems seeing itself as 3.

Comment: Then the bug is in the code you haven't posted.

Comment: Should i post it? As said im new to the site so im not exactly knowledgeable on the rules and so forth and i don't think i could post it without creating a new thread.

Comment: I suggest you 1) replace the entire contents of the `for` loop with `cout << itemno << endl;`, and test that to verify that it prints three lines, 2) pare down the surrounding code as much as you can while preserving this strange behavior, and if you still don't see the bug then 3) post all the code that's left. We are approaching the idea of a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org), a *very* useful technique.

Comment: Do you have a debugger that can step you through the code one line at a time?  If so, just follow it through, and watch how the variables change.  If not, try printing out numItems after each time that it gets changed, to see why it gets the value it does

Comment: @Beta i could share the entire program in a downloadable folder so those who wish to see it can. Im starting to think now that the problem is up in another function in the program where numItems originates. this is the link if you think its wise to post otherwise ill remove it.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgylnriy6vgnkay/Lab10.zip

Comment: 42 kB *compressed??* If you post that deluge of code I'll be the first to vote to delete the question. Read my previous comment: *simplify the code as much as you can* before you post any of it. This is not just for our benefit; you can't be a good coder if you don't learn how to simplify.

Comment: @its 42kb because its 4 separate files our teacher wants us to practice breaking the program up, and it also includes a text file. whole code is about 240 ish lines long if i was to add it all into one file but thats because it has alot of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at all that repetition.  Try this:

```
if (mtype >= 2 && mtype <= 5) {
    for (int itemno = 0; itemno < numItems; itemno++) {
        if (mtype == type[itemno]) {
            price[itemno] = calculatePrice(cost[itemno], hours[itemno]);
            totalCost += cost[itemno];
            totalHour += hours[itemno];
            totalPrice += price[itemno];

            if (mtype == 2) cout << setw(13) << left << canType;
            cout << setw(13) << right << cost[itemno]
                 << setw(16) << setprecision(2) << fixed << hours[itemno]
                 << setw(16) << price[itemno] << "\n\n";
        }
    }
}
cout << "\n" << setw(9) << left << "TOTALS: "
             << setw(5) << right << "$" << setw(12) << totalCost
             << setw(17) << totalHour
             << setw(17) << "$" << setw(5) << totalPrice << "\n\n";
cout << horizontalLine << "\n\n";
cout << flush;
```

Comment: A demonstration of good coding practice, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: where am i using this to replace? the entire for loop?

Comment: @Beta There is not enough information to answer the question and his comments would not have been possible as a *comment*. When information becomes available I'm sure he will update his answer appropriately. I'm inclined to be lenient in this situation.